# How can I assign maximum life time to core threads in ThreadPoolExecuter at Java 1.8

Tags: java, threadpool

Is there a way that we can set maximum life time to core threads in ThreadPoolExecutor ? For example core thread must die after 1 hour of working.

There is **allowCoreThreadTimeOut** parameter but it does not meet the need. Because core thread must wait idle until **keepAliveTime** and because of we have so many task to submit to executor, core thread can live until application stops in theory.

Note: the main reason of my need is undefined memory leak problem that causes to increase thread local storage over time.

Comment: you should locate your memory leak and fix the cause instead of doing things like this

Comment: great idea. but I have to regret to say that we can not specify the exact problem, but we know that it is not from our own application. The oracle driver running on Weblogic puts the jndi connection information on inherited thread local storage each time opening a connection. If you also have a great idea for this problem, please tell me